# How to negate a regex pattern to be used with String replaceAll method?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I wish to get a string that only accepts lowercase alphanumeric characters or `-`. If the string contains any other character it should be replaced with a `-`.

I tried the below regex with look-ahead negation but it appends an extra `-` in the end. How can I fix this?

```
public string sampleTest() {
  String name = "test-7657-hello.WOrld"
  return name.toLowerCase().replaceAll("(?![a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)", "-")
}
```

For eg: Should replace the dot with `-` in the above example.

Comment: You can negate sets by `^`, for example `[^a-z]` but beyond that it's pretty hard. You can't negate an arbitrary pattern easily. There are already some questions with good answers around regarding that topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex**: `([^a-z0-9-])`

For Java `[^a-z0-9-]` to match a single characters not present in the list so they can be replaced by `-`.

**Details**:

- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list `a-z 0-9 -`
- `()` Capturing Group

**Output**:

```
test-7657-hello---rld
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zsg8x6/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace **each** character with a hyphen, use `/[^a-z0-9-]/g`:

```
abcd%$^.efg  -->  abcd----efg
```

In order to replace a **whole** invalid sub-string, use `/[^a-z0-9-]+/g`:

```
abcd%$^.efg  -->  abcd-efg
```

Finally, I warmly suggest you read about the `/g` (global flag) property of regular expression. It'll spare you effort next time.